# Why does Exchange ActiveSync not keep more than 'x' days of mail?

Tags: email, exchange, active-sync

I have a HTC Desire X. I have set Exchange ActiveSync to download past 3 days. However, why does it not keep older mails which are already downloaded? i.e. on Friday, I can see mails from Tuesday on. On Saturdays, I can only from Wednesday on. The Tuesday email which was already downloaded and read is no longer visible?

**Is there a way to make not delete the local copy of older emails?**

There is an earlier question which is similar - [Why does stock email app only keep 25 latest emails?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28780/why-does-stock-email-app-only-keep-25-latest-emails)

However I don't think the accepted answer there is relevant here. From that answer

> to prevent large transfers of data that end up using the device communication thus leading to a faster battery drain;

Why would keeping older mails cause large transfer of data? The older mails are already downloaded and are there on your phone.

> to preserve memory consumption that in turn would leave your device slow and inefficient.

Just because the older mails are there on disk, it will not increase memory consumption. A better way to program it would be display '3' days but have a way to show older ones on demand - since the app would read it from disk only on demand, it wouldn't increase memory consumption.

My phone runs Android 4.0.4.

Comment: [This answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/28782/16265) doesn't talk about phone storage or any other storage you may have, performance and data transfer are mentioned regarding the view and download of 25 emails at a time. Your phone may have 1000 emails, but your app lists only 25 each time, you get 25 more if the end of that list is reached. You can also get 25 new emails if you sync or in some apps if you pull the list down!

Comment: The issue you're having here appears to be related strictly to the application you're using and has nothing to do with the answer and/or question you've referenced. Your problem isn't the view of X emails, you problem as I read it, appears to be the fact that you can only see 4 days at any given time despite the fact that you've setup the app to present more than 3 days (which appears to be working by one day difference)!

Comment: @Zuul - I am using the default mail map which comes with the HTC Desire X - there is no setting on how many days to present. The only settings is how many days to download which I have setup as 3.

Comment: This sounds like an admin policy. Is this a corporate (or otherwise managed) email account?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a setting on your phone or has anything to do with data transfer or memory consumption (at least as far as your device is concerned). I think this is a policy enforced on your Exchange account. Exchange ActiveSync allows account administrators to define policies on how email is delivered to and stored on your device.

Specifically, an email retention policy called [Maximum Email Age](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123783%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) specifies the maximum number of days of email items to synchronize to mobile devices. According to Microsoft, Exchange 2013 allows the following options for this policy (emphasis added):

> All, OneDay, **ThreeDays**, OneWeek, TwoWeeks, OneMonth

HTC has a PDF document that outlines the [Supported Microsoft Exchange Policies in HTC Sense](http://www.htcpro.com/activesync.pdf) (Sense is your phone's stock UI) and this policy is supported by your device. It would seem as though your account's administrator has set this policy to only allow three days' worth of email storage. Justifications for this kind of policy vary; I recommend contacting your account administrator (or whoever operates the Exchange system you use).

Comment: I don't think my account administrator has set a policy that I can store only 3 days of email - because my phone has a setting "Download Past mail" - it can be set to 1, 3, 7, 14, 30 days or all. Now I changed my client setting from 3 to 7, the client is now storing 7 days of email. If I change it to 30 days, it will store 30 days. Basically, the client seems to store the same number of days as number of days to synchronize which is rather stupid. There is no reason to delete already downloaded emails.

Comment: Whether or not that kind of policy seems stupid, I'd check with you administrator. Admins live in their own world with their own rules some times...  :-)

Comment: I am not saying the policy is stupid - I am saying the client is stupid. Because the administrator has not set a policy that I can store only 3 days of email.

Answer (score 0):

This a Policy enforced by the server admin to control the access to mails. It is a normal behavior. The client just sticks to the Exchange policies.
In other case, it is the operators that want the client to behave in this manner.

Comment: Who are the operators?

Comment: I mean to say providers like Verizon, AT&T, sprint etc...they govern all these behavior...